# is there a way to press a candle with my mouse and see the high and low price in wicks?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

is there a way to press a candle with my mouse and see the high and low price in wicks that candle has or had? not open or close price but the max and low price that candle had, in tradingview chart
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to press anything. Just hover your mouse over the candle and you should see it.

[image]

If you want to do such a thing with pinescript, you need to plot that information.